# jQuery - Displaying each image link below it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Firstly here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/krish7878/ajnphekf/).

I am trying to display image url's next to them using jQuery. I've tried using attribute selector but it adds first image url to all images.

Javascript code:

```
$("img").after("<div><a href='http://google.com/'>Text </a></h1></div>");
$img_url = $('img').attr('src');
$("img").after( $img_url);
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="main-container">
     <ul>
        <li>
          <img src="http://img.netzwelt.de/dw677_dh381_sw1920_sh1080_sx0_sy0_sr16x9_nu0/picture/original/2016/01/hoechst-dynamische-frontpartie-tagfahrleuchten-thors-hammer-design-ab-sommer-2016-gibt-neuen-s90-volvo-haendlern-178603.jpeg">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://www.motoroids.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Volvo-Concept-Coupe-300x300.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://www.motoroids.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Volvo-XC90-India-launch-4-300x300.jpg">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Some kind of loop should help achieve this, not sure exactly how. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$('img').each(function(){
    var link = $(this).attr('src');
    $('<div><a href="' + link + '">Text</a></div>').insertAfter(this);
});
```

Any possible doubts, feel free to ask.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. The link just don't show up.

Comment: I don't see it working on your fiddle either. The image URL has to be added after the text FYI.

Comment: Ah! I see you've added it as link to the text.

Comment: Thanks. I will modify the code. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest:

```
$('img').after(function(){
  // this, here, refers to the <img> element in the
  // jQuery collection:
  return '<div><a href="' + this.src + '">' + this.src + '</a></div>';
});
```

References:

- [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/).

Comment: You beat me to it +1 ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.